# p:selectOneMenu does not appear

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I do not know what may have happened to my application that select one PrimeFaces menu is not appearing more. I did not change anything in the code and not the PF style. To test by replacing `h:selectonemenu` and functioned normally. Really do not know what may have been because they were normal until last week.
Use PrimeFaces 5.

[image]

pom.xml

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>5.0</version>  
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId> 
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId> 
    <version>0.7.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I cannot clearly say off the top of my head but to my general usage, the default `<p:selectOneMenu>` appears as that shown in the picture, when it contains zero items i.e. when it is empty (unless you yourself use some extra CSS tricks). Therefore, it should be normal. Does that picture represent an empty `<p:selectOneMenu>`?

Comment: It is not empty when replacing p: selectOneMenu by h: selectOneMenu items appear. I did not change anything in the css it uses the default of Primefaces and until a few days ago functioned normally, this is what intrigues me what may have occurred. I thought of some updating the browser, PF, etc. but found nothing.

Comment: Some CSS classes may have mistakenly been overridden as new functionality is added to the application. Looking into the generated HTML code would help.

Comment: If something appears to fail in client side, always look in browser's HTTP traffic monitor and JS console for clues.